# How do I redraw a string array graphically without overlapping the text?

Tags: java, arrays, string, graphics, repaint

I am trying to display an array graphically but I am having problems.

It shoes "null" before I fill up the array which is fine, but after I fill up the array it draws over the "null" which makes it hard to read.

How can I make it so the canvas clears up and redraws after I fill up the array.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class wordManager extends JFrame
{
String[] array = new String[15];

private BufferedImage buffered;
public wordManager()
{
    super("Word Managery");


    setSize(300,600);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

 public void paint(Graphics window)
 {
     if(buffered==null)
            buffered = (BufferedImage)(createImage(getWidth(),getHeight()));

     Graphics windowTemp = buffered.createGraphics();

     int y = 50;
     for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
     {
        windowTemp.drawString(array[i] + "", 10,y);
        y+=10;

     }

     window.drawImage(buffered, 0, 0, null);
 }


public void read(String filename) throws IOException
{

    String word;
    int i = 0;
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filename+".txt"));
    while(file.hasNext())
    {
        word = file.next();
        array[i] = word;

        i++;
    }
    repaint();
}


public void scramble()
{
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        int a = (int) (Math.random()*array.length);
        String b = array[i];
        array[i] = array[a];
        array[a] = b;
    }
    repaint();
}

public void sort() 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        int s = i-1;
        for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            if (array[j].compareTo(array[s]) < 0)
            {
                 s = j;
            }
        }
         String temp = array[i-1];
         array[i-1] = array[s];
         array[s] = temp;
    }
    repaint();
}


public void write() throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        fileOut.println(array[i]);  
    }

    fileOut.close();

}

public void printArray()
{
    for(String term : array)
    {
        System.out.println(term);
    }
}

}
```

---

```
public class runner
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
{
    wordManager run = new wordManager();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("In put file name");
    String filename = keyboard.next();

    run.read(filename);

    System.out.println("");
    run.printArray();
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Enter 1 if you want to sort\n");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 if you want to scramble");


    int selection = keyboard.nextInt();


        if(selection == 1)
        {
            run.sort();
        }

        if(selection == 2)
        {
            run.scramble();
        }

    run.printArray();
    System.out.println("");

    run.write();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've failed to honor the paint chain.

Paint does a lot of important work, most notably for you, it prepares the graphics for rendering.

`Graphics` is a shared resource, it can get past to all the components that the repaint manager needs to repaint.  Part of the paint process is to clear the graphics, typically by calling `super.paint`.

Now, having said that.  You should, very rarely, need to override the `paint` method of top level container, if for nothing else, top level containers aren't double buffered.

Instead, you should be creating a custom component, from something like `JPanel`, and overriding it's `paintComponent` method.

Text in a graphic environment have metrics, based on the current font.  Simply using a magic number to calculate the next line that the text should appear on is going to produce lots of nasty results when the font changes (and it will).

[image]

Instead, you should be do something like...

```
FontMetrics fm = windowTemp.getFontMetrics();
int y = 50;
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    windowTemp.drawString(array[i] + "", 10,y + fm.getAscent());
    y+=fm.getHeight();
}
```

Take a look at [Working with Text APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html)

Comment: I've always used paintComponent() but my teacher provided us with this new code. 

Now how exactly do I overcome my problem.

I am a beginner.

Comment: If you can't change the code, call `super.paint(window)` as the first line of the `paint` method.  Then get a new teacher ;)

Comment: +1 for the line height calc. I was going to edit my posting but you beat me to it :)

Comment: What exactly does super.paint do?

Comment: `paint` does a lot of things, it paints any child components that you've added to the container, paints any borders, but, most importantly for you, it prepares that graphics for painting, clearing the area with the background color.

Comment: It's good to have a better understanding of things. 

Thanks a lot for you help and explanation.

Comment: You might like to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't override the paint() method of a JFrame (or any other top level window).

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame.

And don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent(...) as the first statement in the method to make sure the background gets cleared.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

Maybe an easier solution is to just display the text in a JTextArea so you don't have to reinvent the3 wheel.

Comment: How would I deal with the overlapping issue?

Comment: My answerr tells you how to deal with this issue. Try it. If you have problems, then repost your SSCCE.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it (:
So was the overlapping happening because the old "temporary" drawing was not cleared?